# How to configure the ServletRegistrationBean for Spring Soap WS

Tags: spring-boot, soap

I have a Spring boot Application which is deployed on tomcat with application context configured in the application.yml to /soapws
I have deployed a SOAP WS at endpoint service.
The ServletRegistrationBean is setup with URL Mapping /soapws

In front of the tomcat application I have apache where I am proxing requests from /soapws/* to the tomcat instance.

I can access my soap WSDL via https://host:port/soapws/soapws/service.wsdl

This is not what I would like
this should be accessible via https://host:port/soapws/service.wsdl but I application does not deploy if set the ServletRegistrationBean with /*

What changes do I need to make?